# Use Salesforce API to extract data into Alteryx

Tags: apache-spark, apache-camel, salesforce, alteryx

I have an Alteryx workflow and wanted to hook it up to import data from Salesforce, specifically Veeva (which sits on Salesforce). I want to use the Salesforce API but not sure how I can do this simply with Alteryx.

Is it possible to use Alteryx with some other software/framework to import data and run it through my ETL process?

I've heard I can possibly use `Apache Spark` but i'm not familiar with it. I've also heard I can possibly use Alteryx with `Apache Camel` but not sure about this either. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find out how to connect to an API in Alteryx at this link:
https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Engine-Works-Blog/REST-API-In-5-Minutes-No-Coding/ba-p/8137
With the Salesforce API, sometimes it can be easiest to use the SOAP API for Authentication and the REST API for download. I'm not entirely sure why, but both Alteryx & Tableau do that behind the scenes for connections.

Basically, you will call out to the SOAP API for authentication, get the Auth Token and use that on subsequent calls to the REST API. The above link should tell you how to implement that in Alteryx.

As for other software/framework for import, the simple answer is Yes. The Tools to look at for this are the R Tool & Run Command Tool. They will let you either import data using an R script or from Command Line (allowing python, js, batch etc).

Spark is supported in Alteryx both natively and using the In-DB scripts. Theoretically you could use Alteryx with Apache Camel, but I don't know enough about the specifics of the Camel endpoints to say that with certainty.